# Pagination using Map not working

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I am trying to use `Map<Question, List<Option>>` for Pagination in my Visualforce Page. I have set pageSize to 1. At first it shows only 1 question and its respective options but when I press Next (>) button, it shows previous question as well as next question. That means, it shows 2 questions with their respective options. Then when I press next again, it shows 3 questions with their options.

I want to show only 1 question and its options on each click. On next it should show the next question and on Previous (<) it should show the last question.

This is my Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class SurveyExtension{
Survey__c survey{get; set;}   
List<Survey_Question__c> ques;
public Map<Survey_Question__c, List<SelectOption>> questions= new Map<Survey_Question__c, List<SelectOption>>();
public String answer{get;set;}  

public SurveyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController con){
    survey = (Survey__c) con.getRecord();
}    
 public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
    get{
        if(setCon == null){
            setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController([select Question__c,Option1__c,Option2__c,Option3__c,Option4__c,Option5__c,Option6__c from Survey_Question__c where Survey__r.id= :survey.id]);
            setCon.setPageSize(1);
            //noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();
        }
        return setCon;
    }set;
}   
public Map<Survey_Question__c, List<SelectOption>> getQuestions(){
    ques = (List<Survey_Question__c>) setCon.getRecords();
    for(Survey_Question__c que: ques){
        List<SelectOption> olist = new List<SelectOption>();
        olist.add(new SelectOption('a',que.Option1__c));
        olist.add(new SelectOption('b',que.Option2__c));
        olist.add(new SelectOption('c',que.Option3__c));
        olist.add(new SelectOption('d',que.Option4__c));
        olist.add(new SelectOption('e',que.Option5__c));
        olist.add(new SelectOption('f',que.Option6__c));
        questions.put(que, olist);
    }
    return questions;  
}
public void first() {
    setCon.first();
}

public void last() {
    setCon.last();
}

public void previous() {
    setCon.previous();
}

public void next() {
    setCon.setPageSize(1);
    setCon.next();
}
public Boolean hasNext {
    get {
        return setCon.getHasNext();
    }
    set;
}
public Boolean hasPrevious {
    get {
        return setCon.getHasPrevious();
    }
    set;
}
}
```

and this is my Visualforce Page :

```
<apex:page standardController="Survey__c" extensions="SurveyExtension">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Survey Title" id="queBlock">                                                      
             <apex:repeat value="{!questions}" var="que">
              Question :  {!que.Question__c} <br/><br/>
              Options : 
                 <apex:repeat value="{!questions[que]}" var="opt">
                    <apex:selectRadio value="{!answer}">                          
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!opt}" />                          
                    </apex:selectRadio>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:repeat> 
            <apex:panelGrid columns="5">
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="queBlock" value="|<" action="{!first}" disabled="{!!hasPrevious}" title="First Page"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="queBlock" value="<" action="{!previous}" disabled="{!!hasPrevious}" title="Previous Page"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="queBlock" value=">" action="{!next}" disabled="{!!hasNext}" title="Next Page"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="fetchStatus" reRender="queBlock" value=">|" action="{!last}" disabled="{!!hasNext}" title="Last Page"/>
                <apex:outputPanel style="color:#4AA02C;font-weight:bold">
                    <apex:actionStatus id="fetchStatus" startText="Fetching..." stopText=""/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:panelGrid>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not re initializing your map variable "questions" in method getQuestions(). You must add a line in method getQuestions() to re initializing map variable "questions". This will make it empty and only 1 question will be added to it afterwards. See the below corrected code of getQuestions() method   -:

```
public Map<Survey_Question__c, List<SelectOption>> getQuestions(){
//---------You must add this below line---------------------------
questions= new Map<Survey_Question__c, List<SelectOption>>();
ques = (List<Survey_Question__c>) setCon.getRecords();
for(Survey_Question__c que: ques){
    List<SelectOption> olist = new List<SelectOption>();
    olist.add(new SelectOption('a',que.Option1__c));
    olist.add(new SelectOption('b',que.Option2__c));
    olist.add(new SelectOption('c',que.Option3__c));
    olist.add(new SelectOption('d',que.Option4__c));
    olist.add(new SelectOption('e',que.Option5__c));
    olist.add(new SelectOption('f',que.Option6__c));
    questions.put(que, olist);
}
return questions;
```

}